# asp.net unable to received email

Tags: asp.net, email

I created a registration page which notify user  after signing-up. The code below works for user under the same domain name but failed to work with outside domain email account. It doesnt return any error and also the receiver doesnt receive email.

```
    ...some codes here...
    string bodymsg="test email";       

    MailMessage mMailMsg = new MailMessage();
    mMailMsg.From = new MailAddress("applications@mydomain.com");
    mMailMsg.To.Add(new MailAddress(mailto));

    mMailMsg.Subject = "test email";
    mMailMsg.Body = bodymsg;
    mMailMsg.IsBodyHtml = true;
    mMailMsg.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;

    SmtpClient msmtpclient = new SmtpClient();

    msmtpclient.Send(mMailMsg);
```

Web.config

```
<mailSettings>
  <smtp>        
    <network host="mail.mydomain.com" password="pwd" userName="applications@mydomain.com" defaultCredentials="false" port="25"/>
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using exchange for the mail transport?

Comment: It's probably being held-up by your exchange server. You may want to see if exchange is blocking them from being sent.

Comment: Yes we are hosting exchange server privately. If thats the case, let me get back after confirmation from exchange logs.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to specify the Server

For example :

```
mMailMsg.Server = [name of your mail server];
```

For example my server IP address is : 192.168.1.137

so I specify :

```
mMailMsg.Server = 192.168.1.137;
```

specify before sending email.

Comment: Carlos Grappa, CAbbott - Tell me what exactly we need to do if the case is true.

Ruchi - Cant find Server property in mMailMsg.

Comment: The issues is with webconfig username it should be given as applications only without domain name.